# Why are tricycles inherently unstable?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, stability

I ride a velomobile which is a [fared tricycle](https://www.velomobiel.nl/quest/) . The trike is a recumbent to enhance aerodynamics so my knees are over the front axle which supports two front wheels and my head partially lies above the rear driving wheel.  A very long chain runs from my feet which are upfront to the sprocket on the driving wheel.

My question is why is the configuration inherently unstable?  There are numerous [videos of velos rolling over](https://vimeo.com/459940955) when they suffer a rear blow out. Typically the rider isn't badly injured since the velo serves as a makeshift roll cage.

In the linked video, the velo was running more or less straight until the rear tire blew. Within a second it had enough lateral momentum to roll the velo onto its side.  Where did that rolling force come from?  Why did lowering the rear wheel result in a rollover?

Does the trike's instability arise from the fact that the center of mass is above the front axle?

Comment: Is it a fact or an assumption that the center of mass is above the front axle.  That's not immediately obvious from the figure give the position of the rider and unknowns about the mass distribution of the vehicle.

Comment: Oh, or did you mean "higher than" rather than "directly above" the front axle?

Comment: I believe a man's center of mass is between navel and pelvis which in this instance, is behind and above the axle.  If you look at the linked schematic images of the velo, you'll see the rider's body is mostly above the front axle.

Comment: The center of mass of the person-vehicle system matters, not just the person. It's not immediately obvious where that is because it's not immediately obvious how the mass of the vehicle is distributed. It might be on the manufacturer's website somewhere, but generally speaking questions should be self-contained here, not require additional research on external sites that might change over time.

Answer (score 0):

On a 4 wheeler the center of mass must move past  either both right wheels, or both left wheels for it to reach the tip over point. On a 3 wheeler the center of mass only has to move past either the right wheel and center wheel or the left wheel and the center wheel to reach the tip over point, which is generally much narrower. The velomobile appears to have a rather narrow track between the two parallel wheels. A wider track increases stability.

Comment: I agree that a wider stance would be more stable.Nonetheless, the bike is very stable going around corners at speed. It's just when the rear tire blows that it's very happy to roll.  What does the blow out do to increase the bike's tendency to roll?

Comment: @Michael A blowout will allow that side to dip lower, which will move the COM closer to that side, while suddenly increasing drag on that wheel decreasing stability and making control harder.

Comment: OP is explicitly asking about a blow out in the back wheel, which is centered. @AdrianHoward